# Stop continuous jQuery each() function on click and add active class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery each() function that loops through a set of three divs adding active to the items within the divs. I'm able to stop the loop on click for my function, but I'm having a hard time making it so that when you click on one of the items of a div, the other items that have the same class stays active. I know I can do it with if statements, but I'm having a hard time figuring it out.

HTML:

```
<div class="list-items loop-set">
   <div class="one">one</div>
   <div class="two">two</div>
   <div class="three">three</div>
</div>
<div class="list-items loop-set">
   <div class="one">one</div>
   <div class="two">two</div>
   <div class="three">three</div>
</div>
<div class="list-items loop-set">
   <div class="one">one</div>
   <div class="two">two</div>
   <div class="three">three</div>
</div>
```

my function:

```
function doLoop() {
var $one = $('.one');
var $two = $('.two');
var $three = $('.three');

var interval = setInterval(function () {
    $('.loop-set').each(function () {
        var $set = $(this);
        var $cur = $set.find('.active').removeClass('active');
        var $next = $cur.next().length ? $cur.next() : $set.children().eq(0);
        $next.addClass('active');
    });
}, 1000);

$('.loop-set').on('click', '> *', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.loop-set .active').removeClass('active');
    if ($this == $one) {
        $one.addClass('active');
    } else if ($this == $two) {
        $two.addClass('active');
    } else if ($this == $three) {
        $three.addClass('active');
    }
    clearInterval(interval);
});;
}
doLoop()
```

I included my code on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/renevilla23/sL95U/2/). Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sL95U/3/ ?

Comment: or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sL95U/4/ ?

Comment: Hi Arun :) 
Close but I'm trying to get the other div's with the same class to stay active too. So if i click on div 'one' - the loop stops and the divs with the class 'one' stay active too.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sL95U/6/

Comment: YES!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! That's what I was looking for! You're the best! A million thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

What about this more simplier code: http://jqversion.com/#!/ndZt3Zz/1

Is this the behaviour you want?

```
$('.loop-set').change(function () {
  var $set = $(this);
  var $cur = $set.find('.active').removeClass('active');
  var $next = $cur.next().length ? $cur.next() : $set.children().eq(0);
  $next.addClass('active');
});

var interval = setInterval(function(){
  $('.loop-set').trigger('change');
}, 1000);

$('.loop-set > div').click(function(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    $('.loop-set > div').removeClass('active');
  $('.' + $(this).attr('class')).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Hi Matei - close. so for example - if i use your code on jqversion, when i click on the first div with the class "one", i'd like the other two divs with the class "one" to have the class active and not looping

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.loop-set').on('click', '> *', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.loop-set .active').removeClass('active');
    $('.loop-set .'+this.className).addClass('active');
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sL95U/6/)

Answer (score 0):

What about changing the onClick to something like this:

```
$('.loop-set').on('click', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $('.loop-set.active').removeClass('active');
        $this.addClass("active");
        clearInterval(interval);
});
```

What it does is it adds active class to loop-set making all of its children bolded. When you click another group - the highlight changes as well.

Here is the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sL95U/5/. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Mike - Thanks for the speedy response. I'm trying to to make the function stop the loop when you click on, for example, the div with class "one" - so when "one" is clicked, the other divs with the class "one" get the class active. So if i click on the div with class "two" the other divs with class "two" get the class active added to them, while class "one" and class "three" dont have the class active.

Comment: yep, true. Sorry for the inconvenience. @Arun P Johny answer seems to be exactly what you are looking for. Cheers.